# How do I say "I held my head in my hands"

Tags: grammar

Recently, I was writing about my time at a funeral. I am trying to express the situation that I was overwhelmed by emotion so I put my head in my hands. (I.e. I rested my head on my hands). Is there a way to translate this into common spoken chinese?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are referring to "put my head in my hands and cried",

My suggestion would be「抱頭痛哭」

> 抱: Holding / 頭: Head /  痛哭: Cry badly

In case you don't stick with "Crying", you can still use it this way:

> I hold my head in my hands as i read his article
>
> 在讀這篇文章的時候，我以手抱頭。

Answer (score 3):

What's your emotion? If you want to express you are shy or embarrassed ,you say 以手掩面。
If you want to express that you are having a rest,you say 用手托着头or 托着下巴

Answer (score 2):

You mean you put your hand above your head? Then that's 以手抚头，表示哀悼.
Or you put your hand on your forehead? That's 用手贴着前额，表示哀悼.
Or you cover your face with your hand? That's 用手覆面，表示哀悼.

Answer (score 1):

我抱著頭, 百感交集

"I held my head, overwhelmed by emotion"